# How to structure data clustering python project?

Tags: python, structure

The project: Read in 2D data, cluster datapoints based on different cluster techniques/models, and evaluate how well the clustering has worked.

Since I am unhappy with my project structure so far, and have little experience with project structures, I hope to get some feedback on how to proceed. The structure is as follows:

```
  /2Dclustering
     __init__.py
     __main__.py   
     __2dcluster.py  
     /cluster_forming
        __init__.py
        __cluster_models.py   
     /evaluate_cluster
        __how_good_is_clustering.py
        __choose_the_better_cluster.py
```

In **main**.py, we read in the input data, and create a 2dcluster object using __2dcluster.py that is then saved as the output. The 2dcluster class uses the function from cluster_forming and evaluate_cluster to form a cluster and adding a metric (i.e.how well did it perfom?) to it. In both subfolders (cluster_forming and evaluate_cluster), we have just files with a bunch of functions instead of classes. My question is:

1.) Does it in general make sense to break everything into so many subfolders?
2.) Would it make sense to have class objects for evaluate_clusters that evaluate_cluster?
 I feel like now it is a little messy but I have no intuition if creating classes would over-complicate things. 
3.) Is there a sensible way of creating classes that deal with all the subclasses, i.e. a class that just combines other classes- or is this nonsense?

If anyone has an intuition on a structure that would make more sense, Id be really happy to hear it. As I said, as someone that has never written bigger projects, I am kind of at loss on what is considered a clever solution and what is overcomplicating the project. Thanks!

Comment: Asking yourself such a question is a good point. Unfortunately **I** cannot know the actual metrics of your project and the usages in your team. The rule is that when a package becomes too large and can be logically splitted then you should split it in subpackages, because it is then easier to assign a subpackage to a programmer/team. But different teams could choose to split at different moment dependings on their usages...

Answer (score 0):

Your project's structure should balance the tension between competing stakeholder's needs.

i) The Coder : This person (probably you) will want to have a number of small, composable functions spread across the codebase where they can be easily tested in isolation, and reused in lots of different ways. The code should be split logically into isolatable, functional blocks that provide clear themes of functionality. Over time, as the codebase gets larger, it pays to split it into ever smaller unit components, to support testing and debugging.

ii) The End-User : This person wants to be able to install your code and be able to run or import it with a minimum of fiddling about. Their priority will be utility, and as such they will want a single point of entry, with a simple interface without having to spend time learning about project structures to get stuff done.

The structure should split the codebase up into different, but meaningful blocks of code, *each of which might exist as elements in their own right*.

The user should be able to run or access your code via a handful of useful entry-points, and the tester/coder should be able to isolate any problem to a discrete function, the fixing of which wont impact anything else in the codebase.

Often, when building a project, it's common to start with a single, monolithic chunk of code, and then over time, split it out into separate units to support maintenance. As a project matures, splitting out commonly reused components into their own utility areas becomes a good strategy - having the foresight to do this from the start is laudable, but not always necessary.

If your project is to do with clustering, then there's likely a workflow that follows the steps outlined: process data, perform clustering, evaluate results - so there's likely going to be a functional split that develops along those lines - but they're all part of a fairly tightly coupled package of functionality, so I'd be tempted to arrange all of these into a single directory - maybe even a single .py file initially, depending on how much code you're likely to generate.

*Possibly*, if you're going to process data in lots of different ways (i.e. not just for clustering) then there might be a case for developing some utility data-reading/processing package that you can hook in for future processing tasks, which would warrant making a different package, or placing in its own sub-directory but that's highly speculative - and presupposes that you'll be bulking this package out with additional (non clustering) functionality/workflows.

I don't think you need to build your own classes on the fly as proposed; A cluster is just a set of associations between object identifiers and groups. Any clustering can be expressed as a set of tuples, where each tuple associates one index(i) with one group(g) with i's drawn from the set I (all your data's indices) and G (the full collection of groups).

One cluster assignment boils down to (i,g) where i ∊ I and g ∊ G

So a full clustering would consist of a list of all [(i,g)] for each i in I, and each associated g in G

Which is likely going to be the same for any cluster/grouping.